# Compare two dictionaries for equality

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dictionary

With C# i want to compare two dictionaries with

- keys as `string` and
- value as a list of `int`s.

I assume two dictionaries to be equal when

- they both have the same keys
- and for each key each value in a list of integers is the same (both not necessarily in the same order).

I use both the answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547351/how-to-compare-two-dictionaries-in-c-sharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470335/comparing-two-dictionaries-for-equal-data-in-c) related question, but both fail my test suite for the test functions `DoesOrderKeysMatter` and `DoesOrderValuesMatter`.

My test suite:

```cs
public static List<int> GetList(int x, int y)
{
   List<int> list = new List<int>();
             list.Add(x);
             list.Add(y);
   return list;
}

public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetDict1()
{
   Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
   dict1.Add("a", GetList(1,2));
   dict1.Add("b", GetList(3,4));
   return dict1;
}

public static Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetDict2()
{
   Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
   dict2.Add("b", GetList(3,4));
   dict2.Add("a", GetList(1,2));
   return dict2;
}
```

The test class

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
    
    
namespace UnitTestProject1
{
  [TestClass]
  public class ProvideReportTests
  {
     [TestMethod]
     public void AreSameDictionariesEqual()
     {
        // arrange
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = GetDict1();    
        // act
        bool dictsAreEqual = false;
        dictsAreEqual = AreDictionariesEqual(dict1, dict1);    
        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(dictsAreEqual, "Dictionaries are not equal");    
     }
    
     [TestMethod]
     public void AreDifferentDictionariesNotEqual()
     {
        // arrange
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = GetDict1();
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();    
        // act
        bool dictsAreEqual = true;
        dictsAreEqual = AreDictionariesEqual(dict1, dict2);    
        // assert
        Assert.IsFalse(dictsAreEqual, "Dictionaries are equal");    
     }
    
     [TestMethod]
     public void DoesOrderKeysMatter()
     {
        // arrange
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = GetDict1();
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2 = GetDict2();    
        // act
        bool dictsAreEqual = false;
        dictsAreEqual = AreDictionariesEqual(dict1, dict2);    
        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(dictsAreEqual, "Dictionaries are not equal");    
    }
    
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoesOrderValuesMatter()
    {
        // arrange
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = GetDict1();    
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        dict2.Add("a", GetList(2,1));
        dict2.Add("b", GetList(3,4));    
        // act
        bool dictsAreEqual = false;
        dictsAreEqual = AreDictionariesEqual(dict1, dict2);    
        // assert
        Assert.IsTrue(dictsAreEqual, "Dictionaries are not equal");    
    }
    
    
     private bool AreDictionariesEqual(Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2)
     {
          return dict1.Keys.Count == dict2.Keys.Count &&
                 dict1.Keys.All(k => dict2.ContainsKey(k) && 
                 object.Equals(dict2[k], dict1[k]));
    
          // also fails:
          //    return dict1.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).SequenceEqual(dict2.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key));
     }
  }
}
```

What is the correct way to compare these kind of dictionaries? Or is there an error in my (admittedly clumsily written) TestSuite?

**Update**

I'm trying to incorporate Servy's answer in my test suite, like below, but I get some errors (underlined with a red wiggly line in Visual Studio):

- `SetEquals` in the `Equals method says: "does not contain a definition for SetEquals accepting a first argument of type Generic.List.
- In AreDictionariesEqual`it says`DictionaryComparer<List> is a type but is used as a variable.`

  ```cs
  namespace UnitTestProject1
  {
      [TestClass]
      public class ProvideReportTests
      {
          [TestMethod]
          // ... same as above    

          private bool AreDictionariesEqual(Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2)
          {
              DictionaryComparer<string, List<int>>(new ListComparer<int>() dc = new DictionaryComparer<string, List<int>>(new ListComparer<int>();
              return dc.Equals(dict1, dict2);

          }

      }

      public class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> :
          IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>
      {
          private IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer;
          public DictionaryComparer(IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer = null)
          {
              this.valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
          }
          public bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> x, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
          {
              if (x.Count != y.Count)
                  return false;
              if (x.Keys.Except(y.Keys).Any())
                  return false;
              if (y.Keys.Except(x.Keys).Any())
                  return false;
              foreach (var pair in x)
                  if (!valueComparer.Equals(pair.Value, y[pair.Key]))
                      return false;
              return true;
          }

          public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
      }

      public class ListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
      {
          private IEqualityComparer<T> valueComparer;
          public ListComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> valueComparer = null)
          {
              this.valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
          }

          public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
          {
              return x.SetEquals(y, valueComparer);
          }

          public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
          {
              throw new NotImplementedException();
          }
      }

      public static bool SetEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
          {
              return new HashSet<T>(second, comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
                  .SetEquals(first);
          }

  }
  ```

Comment: `object.Equals(dict2[k], dict1[k])` compares lists by reference. Different instances of list have different references. It does not matter what items you have in lists

Comment: Your `AreDictionariesEqual` may want to use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)

Comment: @AakashM That would rely on order.  It needs to be order independant.

Comment: @Servy ah of course, I was getting mixed up with `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` I think

Answer (score 32, accepted):

So first we need an equality comparer for dictionaries.  It needs to ensure that they have matching keys and, if they do, compare the values of each key:

```
public class DictionaryComparer<TKey, TValue> :
    IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer;
    public DictionaryComparer(IEqualityComparer<TValue> valueComparer = null)
    {
        this.valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }
    public bool Equals(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> x, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        if (x.Count != y.Count)
            return false;
        if (x.Keys.Except(y.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        if (y.Keys.Except(x.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        foreach (var pair in x)
            if (!valueComparer.Equals(pair.Value, y[pair.Key]))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

but this isn't enough on its own.  We need to compare the values of the dictionary using another custom comparer, not the default comparer as the default list comparer won't look at the values of the list:

```
public class ListComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<List<T>>
{
    private IEqualityComparer<T> valueComparer;
    public ListComparer(IEqualityComparer<T> valueComparer = null)
    {
        this.valueComparer = valueComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals(List<T> x, List<T> y)
    {
        return x.SetEquals(y, valueComparer);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<T> obj)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which uses the following extension method:

```
public static bool SetEquals<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(second, comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default)
        .SetEquals(first);
}
```

Now we can simply write:

```
new DictionaryComparer<string, List<int>>(new ListComparer<int>())
    .Equals(dict1, dict2);
```

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer! I have some trouble getting to incorporate it into my TestSuite, could you look at my update. Thanks!

Comment: @BioGeek Extension methods need to be in static classes.  That class likely isn't static.  And your creation of the comparer is just off.  You stuck `new ListComparer<int>()` in the definition of the type of the comparer, when that's supposed to be the argument to the constructor.

Answer (score 26):

I know this question already has an accepted answer, but I'd like to offer an even simpler alternative:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foo
{
    public static class DictionaryExtensionMethods
    {
        public static bool ContentEquals<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Dictionary<TKey, TValue> otherDictionary)
        {
            return (otherDictionary ?? new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>())
                .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key)
                .SequenceEqual((dictionary ?? new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>())
                                   .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if this could be further improved on by first checking if the `dictionary.Count` is equal to `otherDictionary.Count`. Might speed up execution.

Comment: @KyleFalconer If speed is going to be a concern (if this is going to be executed in a loop of thousands of calls or something like that), then yes, checking the Count first would be a good idea. It would add more lines of code, though, and make it a little more complex, so I would not do that if it was not going to be executed inside a tight loop.

Comment: Nice answer. You need to add `using System.Linq;` for it to compile.

Comment: You also need `using System.Collections.Generic;` I assumed people would figure those out though. :)

Comment: I am a huge fan of simplicity for something like this. Using equality comparer seems overkill if the intended usage is a unit test.

Comment: `SequenceEqual` is being performed on the `kvp`, so how does this solve the problem when either `TKey` and/or `TValue` is a collection or any other type where the  default equality comparer is insufficient?  I do not see how this resolves any problems compared to a very simple answer such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3804852/65004.  _@jfren484's answer does account for either LHS or RHS being null, but otherwise..._

Comment: Yeah, aside from blowing up if you call it on a null dictionary, that one is even simpler than mine. I'd be curious to see the performance of both. I would guess mine would be faster when the 2 dictionaries are not equal (and the closer the difference is to the beginning of the sorted KVPs, the faster mine will be), but when the dictionaries are equal it might swing the other way.

Comment: Looks like null will equal empty dictionary with this.

Comment: @juraj you are correct. I would submit that is the desired behavior, since we're comparing two dictionaries for containing the same contents. A null dictionary variable and an empty dictionary do indeed have the same contents (nothing) so they should match.

Answer (score 11):

Convert the dictionary to a `KeyValuePair` list and then compare as collections:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(
   dict1.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToList(),
   dict2.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).ToList()
);
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that `AreDictionariesEqual()` just needs another method for List comparison

So if order of entries doesn't matter you can try this:

```
  static bool ListEquals(List<int> L1, List<int> L2)
{
    if (L1.Count != L2.Count)
        return false;

    return L1.Except(L2).Count() == 0;
}            
    /*
    if it is ok to change List content you may try
    L1.Sort();
    L2.Sort();
    return L1.SequenceEqual(L2);
    */


static bool DictEquals(Dictionary<string, List<int>> D1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> D2)
{
    if (D1.Count != D2.Count)
        return false;

    return D1.Keys.All(k => D2.ContainsKey(k) && ListEquals(D1[k],D2[k]));

}
```

And if order of entries matters, try this:

```
static bool DictEqualsOrderM(Dictionary<string, List<int>> D1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> D2)
{
    if (D1.Count != D2.Count)
        return false;

    //check keys for equality, than lists.           
    return (D1.Keys.SequenceEqual(D2.Keys) && D1.Keys.All(k => D1[k].SequenceEqual(D2[k])));         
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Most of the answers are iterating the dictionaries multiple times while it should be simple:

```
    static bool AreEqual(IDictionary<string, string> thisItems, IDictionary<string, string> otherItems)
    {
        if (thisItems.Count != otherItems.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        var thisKeys = thisItems.Keys;
        foreach (var key in thisKeys)
        {
            if (!(otherItems.TryGetValue(key, out var value) &&
                  string.Equals(thisItems[key], value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer above will not always return a correct comparison because
using a HashSet to compare 2 lists will not account for duplicate values in the lists.
For instance if the OP had:

```
var dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() { { "A", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 1 } } };
var dict2 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>() { { "A", new List<int>() { 2, 2, 1 } } };
```

Then the result of the dictionary comparison is they are equal, when they are not. The only solution I see is to sort the 2 list and compare the values by index, but I'm sure someone smarter then me can come up with a more efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way using Linq, probably sacrificing some efficiency for tidy code. [The other Linq example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590664/50065) from [jfren484](https://stackoverflow.com/users/666675/jfren484) actually fails the DoesOrderValuesMatter() test, because it depends on the default Equals() for `List<int>`, which is order-dependent.

```
private bool AreDictionariesEqual(Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2)
{
    string dict1string = String.Join(",", dict1.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).Select(kv => kv.Key + ":" + String.Join("|", kv.Value.OrderBy(v => v))));
    string dict2string = String.Join(",", dict2.OrderBy(kv => kv.Key).Select(kv => kv.Key + ":" + String.Join("|", kv.Value.OrderBy(v => v))));

    return dict1string.Equals(dict2string);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If two dictionaries are known to use equivalent implementations of `IEqualityComparer`, and one wishes to regard as equivalent all keys which that implementation regardss as equivalent, they contain the same number of items, and one (arbitrarily chosen) maps all of the elements keys found in the other to corresponding values from the other, they will be equivalent unless or until one of them is modified.  Testing for those conditions will be faster than any approach which does not not assume that both dictionaries use the same `IEqualityComparer`.

If two dictionaries do not use the same implementation of `IEqualityComparer`, they should generally not be considered equivalent regardless of the items they contain.  For example, a `Dictionary<String,String>` with a case-sensitive comparer and one with a case-insensitive comparer, both of which contain the key-value pair ("Fred", "Quimby") are not equivalent, since the latter would map "FRED" to "Quimby", but the former would not.

Only if the dictionaries use the same implementation of `IEqualityComparer`, but if one is interested in a finer-grained definition of key-equality than the one used by the dictionaries and a copy of the key is not stored with each value, it will it be necessary to build a new dictionary for the purpose of testing the original dictionaries for equality.  It may be best to delay this step until the earlier test has suggested that the dictionaries seem to match.  Then build a `Dictionary<TKey,TKey>` which maps each key from one of the dictionaries to itself, and then look up all of the other dictionary's keys in that to make sure that they map to things which match.  If both dictionaries used case-insensitive comparers, and one contained ("Fred", "Quimby") and the other ("FRED", "Quimby"), the new temporary dictionary would map "FRED" to "Fred", and comparing those two strings would reveal that the dictionaries don't match.

Answer (score 1):

I like this approach because it gives more details when the test fails

```
    public void AssertSameDictionary<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> expected,Dictionary<TKey,TValue> actual)
    {
        string d1 = "expected";
        string d2 = "actual";
        Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection keys1= expected.Keys;
        Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.KeyCollection keys2= actual.Keys;
        if (actual.Keys.Count > expected.Keys.Count)
        {
            string tmp = d1;
            d1 = d2;
            d2 = tmp;
            Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection tmpkeys = keys1;
            keys1 = keys2;
            keys2 = tmpkeys;
        }

        foreach(TKey key in keys1)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(keys2.Contains(key), $"key '{key}' of {d1} dict was not found in {d2}");
        }
        foreach (TKey key in expected.Keys)
        {
            //already ensured they both have the same keys
            Assert.AreEqual(expected[key], actual[key], $"for key '{key}'");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IDictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object source)
    {
        var fields = source.GetType().GetFields(
            BindingFlags.GetField |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance).ToDictionary
        (
            propInfo => propInfo.Name,
            propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source) ?? string.Empty
        );

        var properties = source.GetType().GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.GetField |
            BindingFlags.GetProperty |
            BindingFlags.Public |
            BindingFlags.Instance).ToDictionary
        (
            propInfo => propInfo.Name,
            propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(source, null) ?? string.Empty
        );

        return fields.Concat(properties).ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Value); ;
    }
    public static bool EqualsByValue(this object source, object destination)
    {
        var firstDic = source.ToFlattenDictionary();
        var secondDic = destination.ToFlattenDictionary();
        if (firstDic.Count != secondDic.Count)
            return false;
        if (firstDic.Keys.Except(secondDic.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        if (secondDic.Keys.Except(firstDic.Keys).Any())
            return false;
        return firstDic.All(pair =>
          pair.Value.ToString().Equals(secondDic[pair.Key].ToString())
        );
    }
    public static bool IsAnonymousType(this object instance)
    {

        if (instance == null)
            return false;

        return instance.GetType().Namespace == null;
    }
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToFlattenDictionary(this object source, string parentPropertyKey = null, IDictionary<string, object> parentPropertyValue = null)
    {
        var propsDic = parentPropertyValue ?? new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (var item in source.ToDictionary())
        {
            var key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentPropertyKey) ? item.Key : $"{parentPropertyKey}.{item.Key}";
            if (item.Value.IsAnonymousType())
                return item.Value.ToFlattenDictionary(key, propsDic);
            else
                propsDic.Add(key, item.Value);
        }
        return propsDic;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing dictionary using string keys is way more complex than what it looks at first glance.

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` uses an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>` every time you access an entry in the dictionary to compare your input with the actual entries. The comparer is also used for hash calculations, which serves as some kind of index for faster random access to the entries. Trying to compare dictionaries with different comparers may have some side effects on key sorting and equality considerations for the key-value pair. **The key point here is you need to compare the comparers too when comparing dictionaries.**

`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` also provides collections of keys and values, but they are unsorted. The keys and values collections are consistent *inside* the dictionary (the nth key is the nth value's key), but not *across* instances. **This means we'll have to work with `KeyValuePairs<TKey,TValue>` and sort them by key on both dictionaries before comparing them.**

However, the comparers in the dictionary only check for equality, it's not able to *sort* the keys. In order to sort pairs, we'll need a new `IComparer<TKey>` instance, which is another interface than `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`. But there's a trap here: default implementations of these two interfaces are not consistent. When you create a dictionary using the default contructor, the class will instanciate a `GenericEqualityComparer<TKey>` if TKey implements `IEquatable<TKey>`, which require TKey to implement `bool Equals(TKey other);` (otherwise, it will fallback to an ObjectEqualityComparer). If you create default Comparer, that will instanciate a `GenericComparer<TKey>` if TKey implements `IComparable<TKey>`, which will require TKey to implement `int CompareTo(TKey other);` (otherwise it will default to an ObjectComparer). Not all types implement both interfaces, and those who do sometimes use different implementations. There is a risk that two different keys (according to Equals) are sorted identically (according to CompareTo). **In that case, there's a risk on the key sorting consitency.**

Fortunately, string implements both interfaces. Unfortunately, its implementations are *NOT* consistent: CompareTo depends on the current culture to sort items, whereas Equals does not ! **The solution to this problem is to inject a custom comparer to the dictionary, which provides consistent implementation of both interface.** We can use `StringComparer` for that rather than relying on the default implementation. Then we'll simply get the dictionary comparer, cast it, and use it for sorting keys. Also, StringComparer allows comparing the comparers, so we can ensure both dictionaries use the same one.

First, we need a way to compare the values of the dictionary. Since you want to compare lists of int without order, we'll implement an generic equality comparer that sorts items and SequenceEqual them.

```
internal class OrderInsensitiveListComparer<TValue>
    : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<TValue>>
{
    private readonly IComparer<TValue> comparer;

    public OrderInsensitiveListComparer(IComparer<TValue> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] IEnumerable<TValue> x, [AllowNull] IEnumerable<TValue> y)
    {
        return x != null
            && y != null
            && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(
                x.OrderBy(value => value, comparer),
                y.OrderBy(value => value, comparer));
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] IEnumerable<TValue> obj)
    {
        return obj.Aggregate(17, (hash, item) => hash * 23 ^ item.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```

Now, we've got the values covered, but we also need to compare `KeyValuePair`. It is a simple ref struct, so we don't need to check for nulls. We'll simply delegate the comparison to two comparers : one for the key, another for the value.

```
internal class KeyValuePairComparer<TKey, TValue> : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TKey> key;

    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> value;

    public KeyValuePairComparer(
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> key = null,
        IEqualityComparer<TValue> value = null)
    {
        this.key = key ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
        this.value = value ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> x, [AllowNull] KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> y)
    {
        // KeyValuePair is a struct, you can't null check
        return key.Equals(x.Key, y.Key) && value.Equals(x.Value, y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> obj)
    {
        return 17 * 23 ^ obj.Key.GetHashCode() * 23 ^ obj.Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now, we can implement the dictionary comparer. We do null check and compare the dictionaries comparers. Then we consider the dictionary as a simple enumerable of `KeyValuePair` and SequenceEqual them after sorting them by key. For that, we cast the dictionary comparer and delegate the comparison to the KeyValueComparer.

```
internal class DictionaryComparer<TValue> : IEqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, TValue>>
{
    private readonly IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer;

    public DictionaryComparer(
        IEqualityComparer<TValue> comparer = null)
    {
        this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TValue>.Default;
    }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] Dictionary<string, TValue> x, [AllowNull] Dictionary<string, TValue> y)
    {
        return x != null
            && y != null
            && Equals(x.Comparer, y.Comparer)
            && x.Comparer is StringComparer sorter
            && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(
                x.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(pair => pair.Key, sorter),
                y.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(pair => pair.Key, sorter),
                new KeyValuePairComparer<string, TValue>(x.Comparer, comparer));
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] Dictionary<string, TValue> obj)
    {
        return new OrderInsensitiveListComparer<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>>()
            .GetHashCode(obj.AsEnumerable()) * 23 ^ obj.Comparer.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Finally, we only need to instanciate comparers and let them do the work.

```
    private bool AreDictionariesEqual(Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1, Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict2)
    {
        return new DictionaryComparer<List<int>>(
            new OrderInsensitiveListComparer<int>())
                .Equals(dict1, dict2);
    }
```

However, for this to work, we need to use a StringComparer in every dictionary.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoesOrderValuesMatter()
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>(StringComparer.CurrentCulture);
        // more stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function shown below can be accommodated to perform any generic comparison:

```
public bool AreDictionaryEquals(Dictionary<ulong?, string> dictionaryList1, Dictionary<ulong?, string> dictionaryList2)
{

   if (dictionaryList1.Count != dictionaryList2.Count)
      return false;

   IDictionary<ulong?, string> orderedList1 = new Dictionary<ulong?, string>();
   IDictionary<ulong?, string> orderedList2 = new Dictionary<ulong?, string>();

   foreach (var itemDict1 in dictionaryList1.OrderByDescending(key => key.Id))
   {

     orderedList1.Add(itemDict1.Id, itemDict1.PropertyX);

   }

   foreach (var itemDict2 in dictionaryList2.OrderByDescending(key => key.Id))
   {

     orderedList2.Add(itemDict2.Id, itemDict2.PropertyX);

   }

  //check keys and values for equality
  return (orderedList1.Keys.SequenceEqual(orderedList2.Keys) && orderedList1.Keys.All(k => orderedList1[k].SequenceEqual(orderedList2[k])));

}
```

1- If the length of both dictionaries is not equal we can safely return false.

2- Then, we proceed to sort both dictionaries using the value of the keys. The reason for doing this is you could have situations like this:

**Dictionary A:** [1,A], [3,B]

**Dictionary B:** [3,B], [1,A]

Even though the order is not the same, the content of both can be considered equal.

Finally:

3- We compare both sorted sequences and retrieve the result of this comparison.