# C# Compare two dictionaries by filtering the type

Tags: c#, dictionary

I want to compare in C# two dictionaries with as keys a object and as value a list of another object.

For example:

```
class invoice: field 1, field 2, field 3
class details: field A, field B
```

So:

```
Dictionary<invoice, List<details>>
```

These objects are instances of EF, and there are reference fields that I would like to exclude.

I found this post:
[C# Compare two dictionaries for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758074/c-sharp-compare-two-dictionaries-for-equality)

where Servy explains very well.. 
But, you can insert filters?

For example in this post they use Reflection:
[Comparing object properties in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506096/comparing-object-properties-in-c-sharp)

and you could add line such as:

```
if (pi.PropertyType.Namespace != "System") continue;
```

In this way I will take only the desired fields (int, string, byte, etc ...)

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**

I have two objects (dict1 and dict2) type:

```
Dictionary<invoice, List<details>>
```

I would check if the objects's fields (written at the top of the post) are identical.

When working with edmx files (and Database First) an object instance is created also with the properties of references relationship.

In my case, when you create an object of type:

```
Dictionary<invoice, List<details>>
```

I find the relationship properties between the tables (which I would not check).

So, I would like to make a check (between dict1 and dict2) only of the properties (**more precisely, the property values**) listed above

```
field 1, field 2, field 3 (about Keys)

field A, field B (about Values)
```

discarding other relation's field (for example with namespaces like System.Data.Objects.DataClasses).

The reason of this: dict1 is read from the DB and has the NOT NULL relationships.
Instead, dict2 is created by me and relationships are NULL, because I populate only the fields mentioned above. 
So, we need to leave out the check these relationships, otherwise always I'll find differences between dict1 and dict2.

thanks

Comment: I don't really understand what are you asking. Can you please clearly state what is your question/problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compare?

Comment: @All: Post updated.. thks